# Serving GroundOverlay image data from a KML file via WMS

Tags: geoserver, kml, geotiff-tiff

I've got a KML file with a collection of sparsely distributed (and small) GroundOverlays, with each overlay containing a distinct LatLonQuad and Icon.

I would like to serve the this image data via a WMS (ideally GeoServer). The Icons (images) in the KML are aerial photos of real-world objects, so it is imperative that they scale correctly according to the zoom level of the view.

I was thinking of writing a script to convert the KML file to one or more GeoTIFF files or something similar (as described here: [Export georeferenced image overlay from KML?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17420/export-georeferenced-image-overlay-from-kml)), but it feels like that is not the most efficient approach, particularly considering that the GroundOverlays are so sparsely populated.

Another option I was looking at was trying to just create a Shapefile from the KML file and use SLD with a dynamic symbolizer (as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589181/display-image-over-map-layer-in-geoserver) to avoid creating a raster for such sparse data, but I suspect that the icon images will be tiled instead of stretched at different zoom levels, which is not the intention.

Is there a quick and easy way to serve this kind of data via a WMS?